# Ipad Checkboxes

Tags: ipad

How do I use checkboxes in iPad application development?

I want to use this for users to answer questions like:

1.Is the Up Photocell operational?
Yes
No

Then output the results to another page.

I've tried some google searches, with nothing.

Anyone?

Comment: What your problem with that exactly is?

Comment: I basically know how to make them in html, if developing on iOS is it drag and drop to create checkboxes in iOS kind of similiar to how it is in developing in Visual Studio w/ drag and drop?

Answer (score 5):

The UIKit user interface in iOS doesn't use checkboxes, it uses the [**UISwitch control**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

[image: UISwitch controls]

There is no checkbox control.

Comment: Can you show a code sample of how to make a simple checkbox using the UISwitch Control?

Comment: No, because I'm not telling you how to make a checkbox, I'm saying you need to use a UISwitch instead. To add a UISwitch, drag and drop it in Interface Builder, just as you suggested in your question comment. I linked to the class reference in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard checkbox provided by Apple but there are some opensource solutions.  Checkout: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/radiobutton

There are other solutions out there too but that is one.

Comment: How do you get the values of a given checkbox, for instance to output them?

Comment: It should be part of that implementation.  You will have to download the code and see how it works

Comment: I don't want a radio button though, I want a checkbox

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make your own if UISwitch isn't what you want.  Just subclass a UIImageView and put a UITapGestureRecognizer on it.  Every time it is tapped it switches the image and flips a BOOL variable.